# SQL Sum a Sum, or combine

Tags: sql

i need help with the following query it should produce a sum of all the goals made in every match played:

```
SELECT SUM(stand1)
    FROM wedstrijdmodule_wedstrijden 
    WHERE team1 = 25 
UNION
SELECT SUM(stand2)
    FROM wedstrijdmodule_wedstrijden 
    WHERE team2 = 25;
```

it results in:

```
SUM(stand1)
68
77
```

I need:

```
SUM(stand1)
145
```

It's been a while since I did SQL and searched for about an hour, with no results. It doesn't have to look pritty because it will be extracted using php.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer, wrap your query up in a derived table and do another SUM:

```
select sum(sm)
from
(
    SELECT SUM(stand1) as sm
        FROM wedstrijdmodule_wedstrijden 
        WHERE team1 = 25 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUM(stand2)
        FROM wedstrijdmodule_wedstrijden 
        WHERE team2 = 25
) dt
```

Switched to `UNION ALL`, in case the two select returns same number.

Or, use `case` expressions to do conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(case when team1 = 25 then stand1 else 0 end) + 
       SUM(case when team2 = 25 then stand2 else 0 end) 
FROM wedstrijdmodule_wedstrijden 
WHERE team1 = 25 or team2 = 25
```